# How to subtract values using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Could you tell me how can I subtract values?

SQL>

```
select SUM(bytes/1024/1024) from dba_data_files where TABLESPACE_NAME='UNDOTBS1'
```

2  ;

```
SUM(BYTES/1024/1024)
--------------------
            7000
```

SQL>

```
select SUM(BYTES/1024/1024) from DBA_UNDO_EXTENTS where STATUS LIKE 'ACTIVE';

SUM(BYTES/1024/1024)
--------------------
               8
```

I need to get a value 7000 - 8

When I do

```
select SUM(bytes/1024/1024) from dba_data_files where TABLESPACE_NAME='UNDOTBS1'
minus
select SUM(BYTES/1024/1024) from DBA_UNDO_EXTENTS where STATUS='ACTIVE';
```

I get result only from the first select.

Comment: `minus` is not an arithmetic operator, it's a relational operator.

Answer (score 6):

Use the dual pseudo table here and evaluate the sums as scalars:

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT SUM(bytes/1024/1024) as sum_a 
    from dba_data_files where TABLESPACE_NAME='UNDOTBS1')
 - (select SUM(BYTES/1024/1024) as sum_b 
    from DBA_UNDO_EXTENTS where STATUS LIKE 'ACTIVE') as Difference
FROM
    dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Might work:

```
SELECT sum_a-sum_b as result
FROM
    (SELECT SUM(bytes/1024/1024) as sum_a from dba_data_files where TABLESPACE_NAME='UNDOTBS1') as a, 
    (select SUM(BYTES/1024/1024) as sum_b from DBA_UNDO_EXTENTS where STATUS LIKE 'ACTIVE') as b
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of

```
SELECT ...
minus
SELECT...
```

is using a set mathematics approach. It is subtracting the set [8] from the set [7000], leaving it with the set [7000]. Other answers have given you options for resolving this and getting the information you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```
select (SUM(u.bytes) - SUM(a.BYTES)) /1024/1024
from dba_data_files u
   cross join DBA_UNDO_EXTENTS a
where u.TABLESPACE_NAME='UNDOTBS1'
   and a.STATUS='ACTIVE';
```